# Is there documentation for MASS:: as.fractions?

Tags: r, fractions

`as.fractions` is clearly in the MASS library, but searching for its documentation always redirects me to [the docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-50/topics/fractions) for the `fractions` function, which makes no mention of `as.fractions`. So, where, if anywhere, is `as.fractions` documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have any separate documentation because it is just a tiny wrapper around `fractions`. The entire function is

```
function (x) 
if (is.fractions(x)) x else fractions(x)
```

So if the object you are passing is already of class `"fractions"` then the function does nothing at all. If it isn't a `"fractions"` object, it is exactly the same as calling `fractions`. In other words, `as.fractions` is just another name for `fractions`

Comment: "_It doesn't have any separate documentation because it is just a tiny wrapper around fractions._" That's great, but it's odd that the docs never told me that. Is it just something that the user is expected to figure out on their own?

Comment: @J.Mini yes, it's common in documents that deal with functions that create a class to lump three different functions together: the `class`, `as.class` and `is.class` functions. For example `numeric()`, `is.numeric()` and `as.numeric()` are all on the same page. Same with `factor` and `character`. The documents for MASS should probably list `as.fractions` and `is.fractions` on the same page as `fractions`